# Problem with Chromedriver in Headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I would like to know if anyone there has ever had a problem using the chromedriver in "headless" mode. In my case, when running selenium tests in this mode, the execution of the same is stopped indefinitely, not completing the test and starts execution of the next test case nor does it give the relevant exception. I would like to know if anyone can have any idea of what may be occurring. I am guessing this issue is due to static initialization of the webdriver

`public static WebDriver createInstance(WebDriver driver, String browserName){..}`

My logs show me this sequence the test cases are not completely executed and next test case is called

`- INFO learning.helpers.DriverInitialisor - createInstance - 111 - Running Chrome browser in headless mode
- INFO learning.helpers.DriverInitialisor - createInstance - 126 - Launching Chrome browser in local mode
- INFO learning.tests.ExpandFAQ - expandAndCollapseFAQ - 30 - launching the ION Learning Hub Application
- INFO learning.tests.ExpandFAQ - expandAndCollapseFAQ - 35 - Open a searched  product
- INFO learning.helpers.DriverInitialisor - createInstance - 111 - Running Chrome browser in headless mode
- INFO learning.helpers.DriverInitialisor - createInstance - 126 - Launching Chrome browser in local mode
- INFO learning.tests.CollapseFAQ - collapseFAQ - 30 - launching the ION Learning Hub Application
- INFO learning.tests.CollapseFAQ - collapseFAQ - 35 - Open a searched  product`

This continues for few test cases and then complete execution starts again for other test cases. I am running of around 50 test cases. There is no multithreading implemented.

Comment: There is no exception no stacktrace present.

Comment: Please provide us more information about your code. Would you please show us your driver options?

Comment: @KanchanRuia Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: I have updated my question if this would help

Comment: I had this problem on the previous job, on Windows 7 but not Windows 10. Now I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: You might want to switch to FireFox driver. I had also problems with headless Chrome.which disappeared once I switched to FireFox.

Answer (score 15):

I have noticed that in my case and worked perfectly.You need add window size as an arguments in headless Mode.I don't know which language you are working on.

If you are using `python` add this .

```
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
```

if you are using `java` add this.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
```

Please try this and let me know if this work.

Comment: Hi @Kajal Kundu I am using Java. I have already used above mentioned code  
options.addArguments("headless")     
options.addArguments("window-size=1366x768");
options.addArguments("--incognito");

Comment: @KanchanRuia :  `options.addArguments("window-size=1366,768");`

Comment: If is not working you need to increase your window-size dimension.

Comment: @KunduK Thank you. Your solution worked for me. I am using python and I had the same issue. Just a very slight edit (I am sure it was a typo) : Semi colon at the end needs to be removed in python solution

Comment: @Priya : Thanks. I have updated the same.

Answer (score 1):

In `Python`, the chrome driver in `headless` mode sometimes requires the window size. Especially, when you want to perform some actions and navigate through different pages. Not providing the window size opens your driver in an arbitrary size. As a result, the desired elements are not visible.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

If you are not working in `headless` mode, you can instead use:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "./chromedriver", options = chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
```